# Keyboard shortcut for word-wrap in Cloud9

Tags: cloud9-ide

In Cloud9 you can turn word-wrap on/off by going to View > Wrap Lines, or the cog in the bottom-right. But there's no keyboard shortcut for it. The Keybindings editor also doesn't have any commands that match the word "wrap" (except one for Emmet.)

The files my users work on have parts that are best viewed with word wrap on, and parts that are best viewed with it off, so turning word-wrap on globally isn't enough.

Is there some other term I should search for to set up a keyboard shortcut? Or is there no way to turn wrap on/off without the mouse+menus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in command for this,
but you can use the init script feature from the `Cloud9` menu.
Just add:

```
services.commands.addCommand({
    name: "toggleWordWrap",
    bindKey: {win: "alt-shift-w", mac: "alt-shift-w", position: 1000},
    exec: function(editor) {
        editor.setOption("wrap",  editor.getOption("wrap") == "off")
    }, 
    isAvailable: function(editor) {return editor && editor.ace}
}, plugin);
```

`position: 1000` is to ensure command get's higher priority than default commands with the same keybinding

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2016 you can toggle 'soft' word-wrap with <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

You can also find a list of commands in the *Commands* tab on the left

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+q doesn't do anything for me (and there's still no shortcut listed in the menu for View -> Wrap lines.) In User Preferences -> Keybindings -> Keyboard Mode I'm set to default, so maybe Vim/Emacs/Sublime has it? (Though searching the possible keybindings underneath for "Wrap" doesn't find anything either.)

Comment: Odd. I'm using default keybindings too and it works for me.